# Cannot eliminate canvas page in facebook app

Tags: facebook

I have set a canvas page, and now, my facebook app page goes to a horrible place:
http://apps.facebook.com/hificorder/?ref=ts

whereas it is supposed to go to: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=123018831077733

So, set the canvas page to the latter link...right? WRONG....when you do so, it causes an error. Set the canvas page to nothing??? FB does not allow. What do I do???

FYI, when you search for "HiFiCorder" in the normal facebook search, the canvas page is what comes up...this is horrible, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your canvas URL should point to your app hosted on *YOUR server*, it's the landing page to your application on facebook.

While the Facebook Application page is a page *hosted* by facebook which is totally different.

First of all, it's a good Idea to set a canvas page, for example:

> Site URL: http://mydomain.com/fb_app/
>   Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/fb_app/
>   Canvas URL: http://mydomain.com/fb_app/canvas/

So on your server, the structure would be something like:

```
www
   |
    - fb_app
            |
             - app_structure
                            |
                             - ..etc
             - canvas
                     |
                      - index.php // your canvas landing page
```

**EDIT:**
So based on your comment, you want your canvas page to act as the Facebook Application page?
then just in your canvas page add this line:

```
<script>window.top.location = "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=123018831077733"</script>
```

Comment: before I had a canvas URL set though, you would search for HiFiCorder on facebook and it would go to my app's page on facebook. this is what I want....

Comment: @hunterp: and it's doing this now, what's the issue?

Comment: Thanks. Not the fastest of solutions, but it will do.

Comment: @ifaour, In now days, The canvas URL must be `SSL` and start with `https://`, But i don't have that. What should i do??

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the canvas link to nothing, this is allowed when you set the app URL to something.

Comment: __The parameter is required__ now, What should i do??